# When I upgraded my iPad to ios 7, I was forced to restore to factory settings. I lost all of my photos and videos. Are they somewhere?

Tags: icloud

When I upgraded my iPad to ios 7, I was forced to restore to factory settings. I lost all of my photos and videos from the past 3 years. Are they "out there" somewhere?

Comment: Did you make a back up?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever backed up your iPad? Camera roll photos will be in your backup.  If you have ever synced your iPad to iTunes on your computer then you will have a backup on your computer.  If you had iCloud backup turned on then you will have a backup on iCloud. Go to Settings>General>Reset on your iPad and select 'Erase all Content and Settings', follow the prompts and select restore from iTunes Backup and connect your iPad to your computer, or select restore from iCloud Backup and wait for your backup to be downloaded from iCloud over the air.